# Basic bar plot with subset of data frame in R

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with two variables, both of which are factors, education and salary (df). I'd like to make a bar plot but only with a subset of the data, the observations for which education=="high".

For the plot I'd like the xaxis=counts(salary) and the yaxis= salary.
Thanks!

Starting point (df):

```
Df1 <- data.frame(education=c("high","high","high","high","high","college","college","college","college","grad","grad","grad","grad","grad"), salary=c("65","65","65","90","65","65","65","90","90","90","90","65","75","75"))
```

Code so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Df2 <- Df1 %>%
filter(education == "high") %>%
mutate(SCount = sum(n))
ggplot(Df2, aes(x =salary, y=SCount) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
coord_flip())
```

Comment: there is no object `n`, what are you trying to assign to `SCount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few typos in your code... but if I'm interpreting correctly what you are trying to accomplish then this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Df1 <- data.frame(
  education = c("high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "college", "college", "college", "college", "grad", "grad", "grad", "grad", "grad"),
  salary = c("65", "65", "65", "90", "65", "65", "65", "90", "90", "90", "90", "65", "75", "75")
)

Df2 <- Df1 %>%
  filter(education == "high") %>%
  group_by(education, salary) %>%
  summarise(SCount = n())

ggplot(Df2, aes(x = salary, y = SCount)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

..which produces this plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
Df1 <- data.frame(education= c(rep("high",5),rep("college",4),rep("grad",5)),
       salary=rep(c(65,90,65,90,65,75),c(3,1,3,4,1,2)))
library(sjPlot)
sjp.frq(subset(Df1,education == "high")$salary,show.prc= F,show.n = F,coord.flip = T)
```